# List of questions asked on account page

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-accounts

The list of questions I asked on my account page is nice, but I keep finding myself clicking on "next" because the newer questions are listed on later pages.

Assuming that it is more likely that a given user would want to check his newer questions for answers, wouldn't it be better if older questions were moved to later pages rather than newer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can order them by "newest" or "recent". The site will remember your choice.

Comment: All right. Excellent! Overlooked that.